# Postgresql error connection to database failed when setting local environment for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When trying to pull postgresql database through heroku-cli is giving me following error:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to database "d34ferew43d" failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
pg_restore: error: could not read from input file: end of file
 ▸    pg_dump errored with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First step would be making sure you can access it directly from a terminal. So pop open heroku-cli and try to connect directly. If you can, it is probably an issue with your rails configuration. If you can't, you'll want to check your heroku configuration on the server.

This might help:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli

Comment: Thanks for your reply I used command `heroku pg:info` it displayed error missing required fields.